# Necessity of cohomological flatness for the Picard functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow S$ be a proper, flat morphism of complex analytic spaces and let $Pic_{X/S}(T)=H^0(T,R^1 {f_T}_*(\mathcal{O}^*_{X_T}))$ be the relative Picard functor. Here $X_T= X\times_S T$.

Then if $f$ is cohomologically flat in dimension 0, the functor will be representable.

Is the converse also true? Similar question for schemes.
I think I'm missing something very obvious here.

Comment: In the case of schemes, cohomological flatness only implies representability of the Picard functor by an algebraic space. The converse is true if $S$ is reduced, according to Bosch-Lütkebohmert-Raynaud, *Néron Models*, 8.3, Remark 2.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I don't see yet if this can be applied to complex spaces but it seems to me that a similar result should hold.